# how to give notifications when app is minimized in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my android application,I am getting data from internet and I refresh data in every minute.
So my question is:

When application is minimized, i want to inform the users that new data is available via notifications.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `onUserLeaveHint()` of Activity` because this method is called when an activity is about to go into the background as the result of user choice like by pressing Home key , menu key,search key or any incoming phone call.

So when this method is called then start your service for data notifaction because `onUserLeaveHint()` is called when your application is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Set your application in a way that the data receiving and sending is handled by a Service.  From the service, on events of data send/receive, fire up notifications.

In your case, I think its best to use unbound services

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html  or 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/  or http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-downloading-data-with-services/

should be good info about services...  if you wanna know how to fire up notifications, try http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for.html or http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/03/notification-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() 
   { 

        System.out.println("Home Button Pressed");
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```